# Backbone View without model not rendering Handlebars Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to render handlebars template in backbone view but its not rending in both chrome and firefox. Please help me on this. I am not finding errors is console as well.All sources are loading fine.I am alerting during rendering thats works fine.I am not using any model here, only Backbone View, Handlebar Template and HTML, 
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="underscore-min.js"></script>  
<script src="backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="loginStyle.css">    
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="landingpageTemplate">
   <div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="container"> 
     <p>Some Message Can be Used here.</p> 
         <div class="row" style="position:relative;Z-index:0;">   
           <div class=" span3 pull-right loginForm" style="background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">
            <form class="form-horizontal text-center" id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="" method="post">
                <legend>Login</legend>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <input class="input-block-level" type="text" placeholder="Email Id" name="emailField" type="email" id="emailField">
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <input class="input-block-level" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="passwordField" id="passwordField">
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <a href="ccrz__CCForgotPassword?cartID=">Forgot Password</a>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-border">
                </div>                    
            </form>
        </div>
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var compile = $("#landingpageTemplate").html();
    LandingpageView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: Handlebars.compile(compile),
        initialize: function() {
          this.render();
        },
        render: function() {
            alert ("hello");                
            this.$el.html(this.template());
            return this;
        }
    });
    var LandingpageView = new LandingpageView();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of `this.template(this.model)` I think it should be `this.template(this.model.toJSON())`. Otherwise you're passing your whole model to Handlebars, and I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: `LandingpageView = new LandingpageView()` you are overwriting the constructor itself. What do you expect `this.model` to be? Even if it exist you don't seem to have any binding in the template, then why are you  trying pass the model? what do you expect to see? Looks like you have no idea what you're doing voting to close.

Comment: Hi T J ,
I am not using any model here. I want to just render the template.Let me know is it a right way to do

Comment: @Adi but your code contains model. First understand what your code is doing.

Comment: Yes but I thought that is the way of rendering. May be I am wrong ,so what is the way to render the backbone template from backbone(No Model).

Comment: @Adi only the author of posts will get notifications about comments automatically. You should mention other people using `@` so that they will be notified about your reply. Like I commented below the answers, both the existing answers combined should solve your problem - You need to [choose a different variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37612311/2333214) for the view instance and  then  [add it to DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37612407/2333214)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the var next to the View constructor then use a different variable name to create the View instance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var compile = $("#landingpageTemplate").html();
    var LandingpageView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: Handlebars.compile(compile),
        initialize: function() {
          this.render();
        },
        render: function() {
            alert ("hello");                
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));
            return this;
        }
    });
    var landingpageView = new LandingpageView();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After creating the view, you should append it somewhere in the body like:

```
$(document.body).append(landingpageView.el);
```

Also you should either pass model while creating view instance:

```
var LandingpageView = new LandingpageView({model:someModelVariable});
```

**OR** you should remove model from view definition: `this.$el.html(this.template());`

Comment: His view constructor and view instance both has the name `LandingpageView`. So you should explain how he should change it and why he should change it. Or just point to the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37612311/2333214)  or  [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612130/backbone-view-without-model-not-rendering-handlebars-template#comment62709077_37612130) that explains it and then follow up with additional information. Otherwise your answer `$(document.body).append(landingpageView.el);` is incomplete/wrong.